# sql to get listing from paging

Tags: sql, pagination, informix

I have a user list table on my listing page. The data needs to be paged, so how can I make SQL page the data for me (ie. pull the data in sets of 10 records from the table)?

Comment: This question has some useful info for Informix:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033729/informix-subqueries-with-first-option

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Informix has clauses analogous to, but different from, LIMIT and OFFSET:

```
SELECT SKIP n LIMIT m ...
```

You can use FIRST in place of LIMIT.

See the [IDS 11.70 InfoCenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0981.htm), or similar locations for earlier versions of IDS.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you pointed out that you are using Informix, the `LIMIT` clause will not work. Are you able to instead place your selection into an array and call for the desired data from the array?