# Row_number() function for Informix

Tags: sql, database, informix, row-number

Does informix has a function similar to the SQLServer and Oracle's `row_number()`?
I have to make a query using `row_number()` `between` two values, but I don't know how.

This is my query in SQLServer:

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM (SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS ROWNUM FROM table) AS TB 
WHERE TB.ROWNUM BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```

Some help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Row numbers for a query in informix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119278/row-numbers-for-a-query-in-informix)

Comment: Although the possible duplicate question does mention ROW_NUMBER(), one aspect of the problem here is the OVER clause, which is certainly not mentioned in the other question.

Comment: Is this query seeking to get row numbers 10-19, then later 20-29, then ...?  If so, then you should be looking at SKIP and FIRST/LIMIT.

Comment: Yes, at first moment get the 100 first numbers, after get 101-200...Thanks for helping me, I'll try to use Skip and First/Limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as it appears, you are seeking to get first rows 1-100, then rows 101-200, and so on, then you can use a more direct (but non-standard) syntax.  Other DBMS have analogous notations, handled somewhat differently.

To fetch rows 101-200:

```
SELECT SKIP 100 FIRST 100 t.*
  FROM Table AS T
 WHERE ...other criteria...
```

You can use a host variable in place of either literal 100 (or a single prepared statement with different values for the placeholders on different iterations).

Comment: Jonathan, it helped me, but didn't work for Informix 9.40, do you know how to do for this version?

Comment: If the SKIP/FIRST notation isn't in 9.40, then the fix is to upgrade to a current, supported version (11.70, for example).  There really isn't an easy workaround in general SQL.  In ESQL/C, you could use a SCROLL CURSOR and then `FETCH <cursor> ABSOLUTE 101` followed by 99 more `FETCH <cursor>` (aka `FETCH <cursor> NEXT`) operations.

Comment: I'm assuming SKIP/FIRST directives are only available in IDS and not SE?

Comment: Yes, Frank.  There have been no new features in SE for about 15 years now.