# Paging in the stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, informix

I want to make a custom paging according to the following [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx):

but my stored procedure is in informix:

so I search for the equivalent `row_number()` I find this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7421578/418343)

but when I use it in my procedure I get the following error:

> SQL error -944  Cann't use "first","limit","skip" in this context !

---

How to rewrite the stored procedure in the previous link with informix rules?

my procedure has multiple unions is like this:

```
create procedure get_inbox_page(p_emp_num smallint, p_task_code smallint, p_main_code smallint default 0, p_year smallint default 0,p_page int)
returning varchar(60) as v_page_view, varchar(60) as v_task_name, smallint as v_task_code, varchar(60) as v_sp_name, varchar(60) as v_db_name, varchar(60) as v_column_key,  smallint as v_trans_serial, 
    DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(3) as v_trans_date, varchar(60) as v_trans_desc , varchar(60) as v_emp_name, varchar(60) as v_values_key, smallint as v_old_state_serial, 
    smallint as v_new_state_serial, smallint as v_main_code, smallint as v_year, varchar(60) as v_page_new, smallint as v_task_type, smallint as v_task_status,smallint as v_mail_maincode,smallint as v_mail_year,smallint as v_mail_number,smallint as v_trans_year , smallint as candidate_flag ;

Select  ......

UNION 

Select ......

UNION 

Select ......
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `FIRST`, `SKIP` etc, because each `SELECT` statement within the `UNION` collection is self-contained.

Perhaps you could try creating a `VIEW` that encapsulates the `SELECT ... UNION ... SELECT` logic, and then apply the `FIRST`/`SKIP` logic to that.

Comment: Would `SELECT SKIP 100 FIRST 100 * FROM TABLE(MULTISET(SELECT ... UNION SELECT...)` work?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
;
WITH    tempPagedRecord
          AS ( SELECT   Column1 ,
                        Column2 ,
                        Column3
               FROM     TableName AS e--Your query with union 
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   Column1 ,
                        Column2 ,
                        Column3
               FROM     TableName AS e--Your query with union
             )
    SELECT  * ,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Column1 ASC ) AS RowNumber--RowNumber over some column
    FROM    tempPagedRecord 
 WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
```

Comment: This is not Informix syntax, which is what the OP requested.

Comment: The @ notation is not Informix; the OLAP functionality is in Informix 12.10, I believe.